# twig variable does not work inline style background-url

Tags: css, symfony, twig

I have a variable passed as:

```
{% include "Core/Layout/Templates/MYTEMPLATE.html.twig" with {'IMAGE': (positions.why|first).html|striptags } %}
```

when I use it in MYTEMPLATE as a text copy, it works perfectly fine.

*This works*

```
<p> {{ IMAGE }} </p>
```

However when I try to use it to style my section, it does not.

*This **does not** work*

```
<section class="classes" id="id" style="background-image: url('{{ IMAGE }}')">
```

It just does not print style attribute. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Please, could you attach some more code?

Comment: @OscarPérez any specific part?

Comment: How did you verify that the `style` part is not being outputted?

Comment: @SühaBoncukçu what about the included `twig`? With what you posted we cannot see where the `<section...>` is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try dropping the single quotes in your `url()`, it's not needed any way and I'm guessing Twig has some issues with you using single quotes inside double quotes.

So short story shorter, try this:

```
<section class="classes" id="id" style="background-image: url({{ IMAGE }})">
```